# Using a Scala Stream and takeWhile in alphaBeta

Tags: scala

In my version of alphaBeta I'm doing something like this. (`moves` is initially a `Seq[Move]`.)

```
val alphaMovePairs: Stream[(Score, Move)] =
      moves.toStream.scanLeft {
        // Use moves.head as the default best move and 0 as the default best score.
        (0, moves.head)
      } {
        case ((alpha, bestMove), nextMove) => ...
           // evaluate nextMove; compare the result to alpha; update if it's better.
          (newAlpha, newBestMove)
      }
 val validAlpha: Stream[(Score, Move)] = alphaMovePairs.takeWhile { 
           case (alpha, move) => alpha <= beta }
```

My intent was to use the `Stream` and `takeWhile` to avoid evaluating the entire `Stream` of `Moves` if I encounter one that was greater than `beta`. But my trace shows that the entire `Stream` is examined before `takeWhile` is run.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a trimmed down but runnable code snippet? Also, how are you tracing? I don't see how any of the stuff you do would cause a stream to be forced.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the `takeWhile` predicate. It should be `<` rather than `<=`

Comment: Now that this is solved, should I delete the question, or is it worth keeping in case someone else runs into the same problem?

Comment: Nope, you don't have to delete it — you can just post your solution as the answer.